# implementing single page architecture using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a simple single page application web app , I have 2 views in it. can anyone help me to writ the code for 2 things:

1. The first view should load automatically when page loads.
2. The button present in the first view when pressed should make first view to vanish and second view to come on home page.

I am searching the code to establish connection like this from last two days but could not find any thing please let me know if there is a way to do so or not??????

Comment: See this example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute):

> The ngRoute module provides routing and deeplinking services and directives for angular apps.

Comment: oh i got to know any ways ty :-)